# Meaning of "Can you remind me if she will be told?"

Tags: meaning

An English very newbie is here. Can anyone explain what is the meaning of the sentence below?:

Can you remind me if she will be told?

Appreciated. Thanks...

Comment: English very newbies might be very interested in the Stack Exchange site for [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/). It's no big deal that you asked this question here, but it probably would have been a better fit there, and you might want to consider asking future questions at that site instead of this one. That said, please don't misinterpret my suggestion to mean that you're not welcome here; we have many users who frequent both communities, and you are welcome to participate in both places.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Can you remind me** might mean either of two things:

- I did know the thing that I am asking but have forgotten it. Please tell me again now.
- At some future time, I may not remember this important fact. Please bring it to my attention later.

**if she will be told** indicates there is a piece of information relevant to a female person that may or may not be given to her. The particular information is so well known to those in the conversation that it does not need to be stated explicitly.

So I interpret the whole sentence to mean

> We have previously discussed the question of whether or not to pass on the information to a third party. Please tell me again what was decided.

or

> When I meet this woman later, I may have forgotten the decision on whether to give her the information. To avoid a mistake, refresh my memory closer to that time.

In the absence of context, I cannot choose between them.